# 'PKG_NAME' variable in yocto recipe

Tags: yocto, recipe, openembedded

Can anyone help me understand the usage of PKG_NAME variable in yocto recipes. How do we determine its value if we are downloading a package from a certain URI.

Comment: Do you mean PN? I'm not aware of PKG_NAME

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no standard variable called `PKG_NAME` in bitbake recipes. So I presume you mean `PN`.

The meaning of `PN` is given in the Yocto reference manual

> This variable can have two separate functions depending on the
>   context: a recipe name or a resulting package name.
>
> PN refers to a recipe name in the context of a file used by the
>   OpenEmbedded build system as input to create a package. The name is
>   normally extracted from the recipe file name. For example, if the
>   recipe is named expat_2.0.1.bb, then the default value of PN will be
>   "expat".
>
> The variable refers to a package name in the context of a file created
>   or produced by the OpenEmbedded build system.
>
> If applicable, the PN variable also contains any special suffix or
>   prefix. For example, using bash to build packages for the native
>   machine, PN is bash-native. Using bash to build packages for the
>   target and for Multilib, PN would be bash and lib64-bash,
>   respectively.

Thus, within a recipe its value will usually be the name of the bitbake recipe file, less any version numbering.

It has no real relationship to the `SRC_URI` variable except that there is, behind the scenes, a variable named `SRC_URI_pn-${PN}`